# How to concatenate operators in javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators, concatenation

I am writing `next_previous()` function for pagination purpose, I have for loop which is moving from 0 to the given length. I want to use the same loop for two cases from 0 to 10 and from 10 to 0.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}

for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
}
```

to use both cases in one loop I am doing something like this but not working

```
var  i = 0; a = '', b = '';

if(somevar === true){
   i = 0 , a = '++', var b = '<';
}else{
   i = 10 , a = '--', var b = '>';
}

for (i; i +b+ 0; i+a) {
}
```

now problem is javascript not allowing concatenation this way, how can I achieve this?

[See screenshot](http://prntscr.com/hdn64z)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you post a sample of the output you want?

Comment: I have update question with screenshot @Eddie

Comment: I don't know *any* language that allows "concatenation" like this. It looks like you expect `+` to behave like `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach which uses for the logic part ( increment and condition ) functions.

**ES6**

```js
let i = 0;
let a;
let b;
let count = 0;

let somevar = true;

if(somevar) {
   i = 0;
   count = 10;
   a = () => i++;
   b = () => i < count;
} else {
   i = 10;
   count = 0;
   a = () => i--;
   b = () => i > count;
}

for (; b(); a()) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

**ES5**

```js
var i = 0;
var a;
var b;
var count = 0;

var somevar = true;

if(somevar) {
   i = 0;
   count = 10;
   a = function() { i++; };
   b = function() { return i < count; };
} else {
   i = 10;
   count = 0;
   a = function() { i--; };
   b = function() { return i > count; };
}

for (; b(); a()) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Suren can you please do this in javascript.

Comment: This is Javascript :)

Comment: I think it's ECMA SCRIPT or something

Comment: This is just `ES6` specification

Comment: one little question Suren?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159555/discussion-between-nick-taylor-and-suren-srapyan).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are looking for an `eval` solution, but this really is not how one would approach this problem. Rather go for a functional design:

```
function forward(cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) cb(i);
}
function backward(cb) {
    for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) cb(i);
}

const loop = somevar ? forward : backward;
loop(i => {
    …
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is a less-lazy version of @BiswajitPanday's answer. I would have edited his answer instead, but I realized that it's been a week since this question was posted, so an edit on his answer wouldn't be as fruitful since OP wouldn't be notified*

---

Here is an `eval` solution:

```js
function loopFoo(backwardsDirection, callback) {
  if(backwardsDirection === true) {
  var i = 10, b = '>', c = 0, a = '--';
  } else {
  var i = 0, b = '<', c = 10, a = '++'; 
  }

  for (i; eval("i" + b + c); eval("i" + a)) {
  callback(i); 
  }
}


console.log("Forwards:");
loopFoo(false, console.log);

console.log("Backwards:");
loopFoo(true, console.log);

console.log("Forwards:");
loopFoo(false, console.log);
```

That function (`eval`) is generally frowned upon though, I would go with @Bergi's solution, if not that, @Suren's, and if not his either, my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Just use eval(i+b+10) instead of i+b+10

Comment: But `i` is `0` not `"i"`.

Comment: Some int + some string produces a string. As b is string so i will be also a string after concatenate.

Comment: Yes, but it produces the wrong string to be evaluated, at least in the case `eval(i+a)`.